# how to insert date in custom format in sql server table

Tags: datetime, insert

recently i was working on windows based application in .net, where i have form which has field know as Joining date, which datetimepicker control, whenever user submits the form all the details goes in the sql server table, now the issue is for the date of joining field, sql server inserts its own datetime stamp, as the field is datetime type, but i want to insert the joining date as dd.MM.yyyy, so i used Convert.. like below...

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @JoiningDate, 104), i checked this statement in select query with @JoiningDate replaced with GetDate(), it showed me expected results but when i try to insert record, it does not insert record as expected... i am using SP, in sql server 2008, enterprise edition...

can anyone please tell me why this happening... 
please reply as soon as possible as it is of utmost important.

Regards
Abbas Electricwala.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem may have something to do with the type of your table column. you see, if the column's type is datetime,with your convert operation, you are getting the date value the exact way you want it, but since your column type is datetime, sql will insert a datetime value to it.

you can try and change the column type to varchar(10), and see if it makes a difference.